# Validation with regex fails while it shouldn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

```
validates_format_of         :start_time,    :with => /\A\d{2}:{1}\d{2}\z/
```

This is supposed to validate the start time with a format of `00:00`, yet whatever I throw at it, it validates as false thus doesn't let me update the attribute.

What am I missing here?

Somehow the line above also inhibits me from updating other attributes too. Removing the line solves all problems and lets me update any attribute again.

The code that updates the attribute is:

```
if current_restaurant.update(params.require(:restaurant).permit(:start_time))
    //success handling
else 
    //failure handling
end
```

Upon further inspection the params consist of:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", 
    "restaurant"=>
        {"start_time"=>"00:00"}, 
         "action"=>"update", 
         "controller"=>"restaurants"}
```

Comment: The regex itself is ok, in that it matches "00:00".  It also matches "99:99", though.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the information given, since `/\A\d{2}:{1}\d{2}\z/ === "00:00"` returns true.

Comment: What is the type of the `start_time` column? How are you setting its value? When you have an instance of this model in the Rails console that fails validation, what does `instance.start_time.inspect` return?

Comment: Off topic, but the `:{1}` is just a long way of saying `:`. So the regex could be shortened to /\A\d\d:\d\d\z/ and it would be more readable also.

Comment: @Jordan: t.string, :start_time null: false, default:"", it returns ""

Comment: Did you check the validation from console? `Model.new(:start_time => "10:10").valid?`

Comment: If `instance.start_time.inspect` returns `""`, that means the string is empty, which is why validation fails. Could you show us the code you're using to set the attribute?

Comment: @jordan the default value in the database is "" (i should probably change that....) but the params are passed on correctly I believe.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. With an instance for which you believe you have correctly assigned `start_time`, but which is failing validation, what does `instance.start_time.inspect` return?

Comment: @Jordan it returns "00:00" when "00:00" has been submitted, the problem is also that all other attributes get locked(?), since I also cannot update any other attributes.

Comment: Then I have no idea. I would venture to guess that your problem has to do with something other than that validation. You could see if changing the Regexp (e.g. to something that will always pass, like `/./`) gives a different result.

Comment: Solved it, thank you all for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the key problem in my question was:

> Somehow the line above also inhibits me from updating other attributes too. Removing the line solves all problems and lets me update any attribute again.

Therefore I tried allowing for blank in combination with a regex, which happens to fix my problem!

Solution:

```
validates_format_of    :start_time,    :with           => /\A\d{2}:{1}\d{2}\z/ ,
                                       :allow_blank    => true
```

edit:
a better regex for time_validation would be:

```
/\A([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\z/
```